# Coordinate Rotation

Tags: java, coordinate, imagej

I need to rotate the coordinates of the pixels of an image (or a matrix).
My aim is to calculate, for each point, where it will be positioned after a rotation, and vice versa.
I'm currently using this procedure:

```
private void setRot(int i) {
    this.rot = -i / (180.0 / Math.PI);
    this.coseno = Math.cos(rot);
    this.seno = Math.sin(rot);
}

private Point ruota(int x, int y){

    int centerY=h/2;
    int centerX=w/2;


    int j = (int) (coseno * (x-centerX) - seno * (y-centerY) + centerX);
    int i = (int) (seno * (x-centerX) + coseno * (y-centerY) + centerY);

    return new Point(j,i);
}
```

However, if you apply a test, using the method for each pixel, the result is not rotated about the center.

```
    private void esegui() {

        for(int i=0;i<w;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<h;j++){
                Point p = ruota(i,j); //ip : origina image | ip2 destination image
                ip2.putPixel(p.x, p.y, ip.getPixel(i, j));
            }
        nu.setProcessor(ip); // destination image
        nu.repaintWindow();
    }
```

Would someone help me make a proper rotation in one direction and in the other?

this is my Test Class:

```
private int getH(){ //height of destination image
    return (int) (this.h*Math.abs(coseno) + this.w*Math.abs(seno));
}
private int getW(){
    return (int) (this.plus.getHeight()*Math.abs(seno) + this.plus.getWidth()*Math.abs(coseno));
}

public Test(){ // class test
    IJ.open();
    this.plus = IJ.getImage();
    ip = plus.getProcessor();
    this.h = this.plus.getHeight(); // height of start image
    this.w = this.plus.getWidth();
    setRot(14);                     // rotation of 14°
    dHeight = this.getH();          // dimension of the target image
    dWidth = this.getW();
    System.out.println("h "+h+" gh  " + getH());
    System.out.println("w "+w+" gw  " + getW());

    // create an image target
    this.nu = NewImage.createRGBImage("rotate", getW(), getH(), 1, NewImage.FILL_BLACK);
    ip2 = nu.getProcessor();
    esegui();
    nu.setProcessor(ip2);
    nu.show();
}
```

Comment: I suggest to use an AffineTransform instead, which is Java2D's default method to transform coordinates.

Comment: You say the result is not rotated about the center, could you please tell us what it is rotated about (some corner, some random point, etc).

Comment: @CrazyCasta the rotation does not occur at a precise point.
the center of rotation appears to be more moved to the upper left, so it appears the image is not completely at the destination.
I think the problem is due to the fact that the center is different for the two images, the target image is larger.

Comment: @Pierock I think we're going to need some more information regarding what class this setRoa and ruota methods are in and where you create it. Specifically I think we need to know where w/h are coming from.

Comment: @CrazyCasta I edited the post by inserting the class constructor.
h & w are respectively the height and depth of the original image.

Comment: @CrazyCasta The transformation we seek is inside the class [ColorProcessor](http://imagej.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.43b/classij_1_1process_1_1ColorProcessor_d4fb2476f17d5f5ddabf05bd4697a318.html#d4fb2476f17d5f5ddabf05bd4697a318).  The method works well, performing a rotation on the center of the image, but the rotation is performed on an image the same size as the original image.
starting from this method I have tried to adapt it to allow conversion of the coordinates of a target image resized. but I can not.  **note**   consider roiY = roiX = 0;  roiWidth = width ; roiHeight = height;